# read image using openCV from QFileDialog Python

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, anaconda

i am trying to apply pre-processing to the uploaded image.
but the image is not read with opencv, all preprocessing is not applying. 
*PyQt5 - mainWindow:*

```
fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 'c:\\', "Image files (*.jpg *.gif *.png)")
imagePath = fname[0]

extractedText=imageToText.getImage(imagePath)
```

----another class for image --------

```
def getImage(string):
        img= cv2.imread(string)
        finalImage = pre_processing(img)
        extractedText = "anything"
        return extractedText 
    def pre_processing(img):
        resized = img
        if (img.shape[1] > 500) and (img.shape[0] > 500): #error (no shape)
           resized = cv2.resize(img,None, fx=0.8,fy=0.8, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # error in cvtcolor
        th_val, th_img = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th_img, (3, 3), 0)
        return blur
```

is it the problem from the path? or the file type is not compatible with opencv?
before i was using cv2.imread('test.jpg') 
but now with "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName" nothing is working well
The problem from (imagePath)

Error:

```
OpenCV(3.4.2)
c:\miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253:
error: (-215:Assertion failed)
VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth)
in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper'
```

Comment: What kind of image have you read? What is the output of `print(imagePath)`?

Comment: this is one of them, before i apply PyQt the code was working perfectly i was using cv2.imread('test.jpg') , but now with "QFileDialog.getOpenFileName" not everything is working, i think the problem from it @eyllanesc

Comment: the output of imagePath:  C:/Users/Desktop/lab/test.jpg @eyllanesc

Comment: If you use the `cv2.imread('C:/Users/Desktop/lab/test.jpg')` route directly by removing only the QFileDialog, do you have the same problem? PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Comment: no, i tried cv2.imread('C:/Users/Desktop/lab/test.jpg') now with no errors @eyllanesc - PyQT5

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with PyQt since the error occurs in a later part

Comment: @eyllanesc the problem from (QFileDialog.getOpenFileName) , because without it no error occur even if i put the full path from C:\ to img

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc i added extra details in my question, ok thank you!

Comment: as for me you have to add folder to filename which you get from `QFileDialog` to get full path and then use this full path in `cv2`

Comment: you should display path which you get and check if it is really the same file when you load before. Maybe you load file with the same name but from different folder or it is empty file, or it is file with wrong extension - ie. it has `.jpg` but originaly it had `.png`. SO all problem is in loaded file.

Answer (score 0):

The following code opens a image from the path supplied by QFileDialog. Its not clear what your imageToText class is doing, so the problem probably lies in there. Use cv2.imread() instead and work with the returned matrix.

```
class(QMainWindow):
__init__(self):
    self.openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), 'Open', self)
    self.openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+l')
    self.openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
    self.openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)
    menubar = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(self.openFile)
    self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    self.resize(800, 600)

def showDialog(self):
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'open file', '/home')
    print(fname[0])
    import cv2
    a = cv2.imread(fname[0])
    cv2.imshow("a", a)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: the errors for pre-processing still appearing, like this one  error: OpenCV(3.4.2) c:\miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper' and i read this errors happen because of the path @fogx

Comment: then you are selecting an invalid image. fname[0] returns the full, absolute path as a string, which you can see in the command line from the print statement. Also maybe update openCV... newest version is 4.1.2